# Moving Image Inside Post to Product Image in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My old theme doesn't support Woocommerce and I'm currently upgrading my friend site to Woocommerce.
The old theme use post to display the product and I have successfully change the post type to product in order to be displayed in Woocommerce catalog.

The problem is she put the product image inside the post. Is there a way to set the image inside the post as the product image with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple script to move them..
Works with Wordpress 4.4.2

```
// Product which doesn't have _thumbnail_id
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM `25c4_posts` WHERE post_type = 'product' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM 25c4_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $post_id = $row['ID'];
    $meta_key = '_thumbnail_id';

    // GET attachment_id. How?
    $get_attachments_query = "SELECT ID FROM 25c4_posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post_id." AND post_type='attachment' LIMIT 1";
    $get_attachments = $con->query($get_attachments_query);
    $attachments = $get_attachments->fetch();
    $attachment_id = $attachments[0];

    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO 25c4_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (:post_id, :meta_key, :meta_value)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':meta_key', $meta_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(':meta_value', $attachment_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "<p>post_id: ".$post_id." | attachment_id: ".$attachment_id."<BR />".$get_attachments_query."</p>";
}
```

ps: Don't forget to add your own database connection on the top script

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are several ways.

Firstly, just have to find out the attachment id in the post (probably in the db field wp_posts->post_content) and secondly assign it as a product image / thumbnail to the product.

To do this you have to add a post meta entry (wp_post_meta) for the post id, where meta field would be "_thumbnail_id" and meta value should be the attachment id you found in the post's content.

Alternatively you could to both steps in the wp-admin.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea!